# CheckingWinner Method for my TicTacToe game

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I try to get a checkgamewinner method working for my TicTacToe game, but I have problems with the loop even starting or my like ending. Whenever I start to open my game and click on a field it just spams "no winner" as a print. Here is my current code :

```
public String checkGameWinner(char [][]grid) {
    boolean winner = false;
    String result = "None";
    while(!winner) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (gridAt(0, 0) == 'x' & gridAt(0, 1) == 'x' & gridAt(0, 2) == 'x') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player x has won");
                    break;
                } else if (gridAt(0, 0) == 'x' & gridAt(1, 0) == 'x' & gridAt(2, 0) == 'x') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player x has won");
                    break;
                } else if (gridAt(0, 0) == 'x' & gridAt(1, 1) == 'x' & gridAt(2, 2) == 'x') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player x has won");
                    break;
                } else if (gridAt(1, 0) == 'x' & gridAt(1, 1) == 'x' & gridAt(1, 2) == 'x') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player x has won");
                    break;
                } else if (gridAt(2, 0) == 'x' & gridAt(2, 1) == 'x' & gridAt(2, 2) == 'x') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player x has won");
                    break;
                } else if (gridAt(0, 1) == 'x' & gridAt(1, 1) == 'x' & gridAt(2, 1) == 'x') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player x has won");
                    break;
                } else if (gridAt(0, 2) == 'x' & gridAt(1, 2) == 'x' & gridAt(2, 2) == 'x') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player x has won");
                    break;
                } else if (gridAt(0, 2) == 'x' & gridAt(1, 1) == 'x' & gridAt(2, 0) == 'x') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player x has won");
                    break;
                } else if (gridAt(0, 0) == 'x' & gridAt(0, 1) == 'x' & gridAt(0, 2) == 'x') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player x has won");
                    break;
                } else if (gridAt(0, 0) == 'o' & gridAt(1, 0) == 'o' & gridAt(2, 0) == 'o') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player o has won");
                } else if (gridAt(0, 0) == 'o' & gridAt(1, 1) == 'o' & gridAt(2, 2) == 'o') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player o has won");
                } else if (gridAt(1, 0) == 'o' & gridAt(1, 1) == 'o' & gridAt(1, 2) == 'o') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player o has won");
                } else if (gridAt(2, 0) == 'o' & gridAt(2, 1) == 'o' & gridAt(2, 2) == 'o') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player o has won");
                } else if (gridAt(0, 1) == 'o' & gridAt(1, 1) == 'o' & gridAt(2, 1) == 'o') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player o has won");
                } else if (gridAt(0, 2) == 'o' & gridAt(1, 2) == 'o' & gridAt(2, 2) == 'o') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player o has won");
                } else if (gridAt(0, 2) == 'o' & gridAt(1, 1) == 'o' & gridAt(2, 0) == 'o') {
                    winner = true;
                    System.out.println("Player o has won");
                } else {
                    result = "no winner";
                    System.out.println(result);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

No clue what else I could do, I played a bit around with the booleans but then it just didn't stop when there was a winner on my board.

Comment: Please check after replacing '&' by '&&'.

Comment: Sadly this did not change anything, already tried myself..it still just spamms out "no winner" or does not end at all when my grid is full or there is a winner

Comment: Try to debuge your code.

Comment: Both `&` and `&&` work but `&&` is more efficient because the condition will short circuit at the first false evaluation.

Comment: Why are you using loops when you check with hardcoded indices?  And why not just print who won and do a `return true`?  You don't need a while loop either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use loops and if else conditions together. I have created sample program with if else conditions.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char [][]grid = {
                {'x', 'x', 'x'},
                {'x', 'x', 'x'},
                {'x', 'x', 'x'}
        };
        checkGameWinner(grid);
    }

    public static String checkGameWinner(char [][]grid) {
        String result = "None";
        boolean winner = true;
        if (grid[0][0] == 'x' && grid[0][1] == 'x' && grid[0][2] == 'x') {
            result = "Player x has won";
        } else if (grid[0][0] == 'x' && grid[1][0] == 'x' && grid[2][0] == 'x') {
            result = "Player x has won";
        } else if (grid[0][0] == 'x' && grid[1][1] == 'x' && grid[2][2] == 'x') {
            result = "Player x has won";
        } else if (grid[1][0] == 'x' && grid[1][1] == 'x' && grid[1][2] == 'x') {
            result = "Player x has won";
        } else if (grid[2][0] == 'x' && grid[2][1] == 'x' && grid[2][2] == 'x') {
            result = "Player x has won";
        } else if (grid[0][1] == 'x' && grid[1][1] == 'x' && grid[2][1] == 'x') {
            result = "Player x has won";
        } else if (grid[0][2] == 'x' && grid[1][2] == 'x' && grid[2][2] == 'x') {
            result = "Player x has won";
        } else if (grid[0][2] == 'x' && grid[1][1] == 'x' && grid[2][0] == 'x') {
            result = "Player x has won";
        } else if (grid[0][0] == 'x' && grid[0][1] == 'x' && grid[0][2] == 'x') {
            result = "Player x has won";
        } else if (grid[0][0] == 'o' && grid[1][0] == 'o' && grid[2][0] == 'o') {
            result = "Player o has won";
        } else if (grid[0][0] == 'o' && grid[1][1] == 'o' && grid[2][2] == 'o') {
            result = "Player o has won";
        } else if (grid[1][0] == 'o' && grid[1][1] == 'o' && grid[1][2] == 'o') {
            result = "Player o has won";
        } else if (grid[2][0] == 'o' && grid[2][1] == 'o' && grid[2][2] == 'o') {
            result = "Player o has won";
        } else if (grid[0][1] == 'o' && grid[1][1] == 'o' && grid[2][1] == 'o') {
            result = "Player o has won";
        } else if (grid[0][2] == 'o' && grid[1][2] == 'o' && grid[2][2] == 'o') {
            result = "Player o has won";
        } else if (grid[0][2] == 'o' && grid[1][1] == 'o' && grid[2][0] == 'o') {
            result = "Player o has won";
        } else {
            result = "no winner";
            winner = false;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Above is not best possible way to solve given problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it easy on yourself and create methods like so.

```
private boolean checkRows() {
}
private boolean checkColumns() {
}
private boolean checkDiagnonals() {
}
```

Then you have fewer tests within each method and they can be more easily debugged as individual methods.

```
if (checkRows() || checkColumns() || checkDiagonals()) {
  // winning code here.
}
```

I assumed they would be instance methods so they would have access to `char[][] grid`.

Regarding your current code.

- Get rid of the while loop, it serves no purpose
- Get rid of the for loops. You're already checking explicit indices.
- when you decide who won, print it and simply `return true`.
- If you get to the end of all tests with no winner, `return false`.

To debug, establish test cases for both `x` and `o` so you know where to look

Answer (score -1):

I haven't checked your logic but from what I see, what you mention your problem is because of when you open your game, your grid will be completely empty and hence it will go to else block and execute it.

I hope this will guide you to proper direction of how to write your logic properly.

Also, try to divide you methods properly so it will be easy to read, debug and maintain.